# Is there a pressure point under the nose that can eliminate the urge to sneeze?

Tags: environmental-health, placebo

> There's a pressure point under your nose that, if you press it, temporarily stops the sneeze reflex.
>   http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AntiSneezeFinger

One of several places this is written about. Now, when I hear "pressure point", I immediately get vigilant. However, supposedly, this doesn't have to do with homeopathic Qi, but rather on a nerve transmitting the sneezing impulse.

This is **my** go-to method for preventing a sneeze. I'm curious whether it's simply due to the placebo effect, or if there is any truth to the explanations.

Comment: The placebo effect is a true effect.

Comment: @gerrit Of course. However, my question is whether there is a physiological effect to support the claim. Maybe I should have clarified that better.

Comment: @gerrit That is debated. See [Placebo interventions for all clinical conditions](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20091554). "*We did not find that placebo interventions have important clinical effects in general. However, in certain settings placebo interventions can influence patient-reported outcomes, especially pain and nausea, though it is difficult to distinguish patient-reported effects of placebo from biased reporting.*" The placebo effect is better called "the effect in the placebo group".

Comment: @gerrit See also: http://jnci.oxfordjournals.org/content/95/1/2.long.

Comment: @gerrit Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Articuno I don't have a reference for that.  I meant that if someone *believes* there is an effect, then there *is* an effect, because the belief is something in the brain.  I did not mean to claim that it has the desired effect.

Comment: @gerrit Ah, so you mean the effect of the belief is simply the belief itself? A thing can be its own effect?

Comment: @Articuno: I read it as simply saying the placebo effect can be effective, for some conditions. You seem to be taking it into Chopra territory :-)

Comment: @Articuno Belief can have very strong effects!

Comment: @gerrit again, do you have a reference? The systematic review found that the placebo interventions *did not* have important clinical effects.

Comment: @odd How is this Chopra territory? Gerrit said the placebo effect is real and I showed evidence that that assertion has not been proven.

Comment: @DarkLightA don't think it's placebo.  Good explanation for it by interfering with other impulses from the trigeminal nerve that might be stimulating the sneeze.  Like gate theory.

Comment: Ask an (S)DM, if there is such a thing, they would know about it since they really need it.

Answer (score 1):

In this first comprehensive review of the sneeze reflex in the English literature, there is no mention of how a sneeze might be suppressed. [1]

**The sneeze reflex**

> The sneezing reflex may be divided into two phases. The first is a
>   nasal or sensitive phase, following stimulation of the nasal mucosa by
>   chemical or physical irritants. Many distal branches of trigeminal
>   nerve terminate in the facial skin transmitting tactile, pain and
>   temperature sensations, while some branches distribute in the nasal
>   mucosal epithelium [Nishino, 2000]. These branches are myelinated
>   sensory fibers of small diameter, which terminate with receptor
>   endings. Some of these receptors are triggered by chemical stimuli
>   while others are sensitive to tactile and mechanical stimuli [Nishino,
>   2000]. Afferent neural stimuli are transmitted to the trigeminal
>   ganglion via anterior ethmoidal, posterior nasal, infraorbital and
>   ophthalmic branches of the trigeminal nerve [Wallois et al. 1991].
>   Through the trigeminal ganglion the stimuli reach the sneezing center
>   in the lateral medulla [Suranyi, 2001]. Upon reaching a threshold, the
>   second phase – the efferent or respiratory phase – begins once a
>   critical number of inspiratory and expiratory neuron has been
>   recruited [Batsel and Lines, 1975]. This consists of eye closing, deep
>   inspiration, and then a forced expiration with initial closing of the
>   glottis, and increasing intrapulmonary pressure. The sudden dilatation
>   of the glottis gives rise to an explosive exit of air through the
>   mouth and nose, washing out mucosal debris and irritants.

However, in addition to stimulation of the trigeminal nerve as documented above, there are other causes of sneezing as listed below:

- Rhinitis
- Photic sneeze reflex (ACHOO syndrome)
- Physical stimulations of the trigeminal nerve
- Central nervous system pathologies
- Psychogenic (intractable) sneezing
- Snatiation* reflex
- Sexual ideation or orgasm

Thus to interrupt the sneeze reflex before it reaches its explosive conclusion, one can try interfering with the causes by:

- closing your eyes to suppress the photic sneeze reflex
- further stimulate the trigeminal nerve by pinching parts of your face
- cease sexual activity

Good luck.

---

[1] Songu M, Cingi C. [Sneeze reflex: facts and fiction.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19617285) Ther Adv Respir Dis. 2009 Jun;3(3):131-41. doi: [10.1177/1753465809340571](http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/1753465809340571). PubMed PMID: 19617285. [Medscape full text](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/714420)